# How to solve oracle joins when trying to give input dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am lucky and i am new to oracle.

I need to retrieve the data from emp table and dept table based on given input deptno and JOB

```
SELECT

ENAME, E.DEPTNO, JOB , LOC FROM

EMP E , DEPT D where e.deptno=&dno and job ='&JOB' ;
```

if I enter 10 and clerk

If I write query like this it needs to display only MILLER Record only but the output like as below

```
MILLER    10    CLERK    NEW YORK

MILLER    10    CLERK    DALLAS

MILLER    10    CLERK    CHICAGO

MILLER    10    CLERK    BOSTON
```

But i need output like

```
 MILLER    10    CLERK    NEW YORK
```

because he belongs to 10th dept and the location is NEW YORK
Please help me on this.

Comment: That is already only MILLER record, what is your problem? Show us your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join emp and dept table try

```
SELECT

ENAME, E.DEPTNO, JOB , LOC FROM

EMP E , DEPT D where e.deptno=&dno 
and e.deptno=d.deptno 
and job ='&JOB' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i need output like
>
> ```
>  MILLER    10    CLERK    NEW YORK
> ```

Then you MUST **join** both the tables on **DEPTNO**. You are doing a **CARTESIAN** join, and therefore it returns you all the 4 rows from **DEPT** table for one row in **EMP** table.

You have missed the JOIN condition. So, you need to add this condition:

```
WHERE e.deptno= d.deptno
```

**Test case:**

```
SQL> SELECT ENAME,
  2    E.DEPTNO,
  3    JOB ,
  4    LOC
  5  FROM EMP E ,
  6    DEPT D
  7  WHERE e.deptno= d.deptno --> Join condition
  8  AND E.DEPTNO = &DNO
  9  AND job ='&JOB';
Enter value for dno: 10
old   8: AND E.DEPTNO = &DNO
new   8: AND E.DEPTNO = 10
Enter value for job: CLERK
old   9: AND job ='&JOB'
new   9: AND job ='CLERK'

ENAME          DEPTNO JOB       LOC
---------- ---------- --------- -------------
MILLER             10 CLERK     NEW YORK

SQL>
```